# strtok_r продолжает обрезать слово

Tags: c, strtok

```
char requete[BUFLEN];
Frame recv_packet;
// select 
if ((recvfrom(fd, requete, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &lenclient) == -1))
                // error

recv_packet = from_char_to_struct(requete);
char* req = recv_packet.packet.data;

printf("req is %s of size %ld\n",req, strlen(req));
// req is taille of size 6
while ((nom_serveur = strtok_r(req," ", &req)) != NULL)
{
     //нарезка
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что, например при условии,что req="taille" и его длина равна 6, вход в while происходит два раза: первый раз с nom_serveur=taille,а во второй раз с nom_serveur равным случайным набором знаков. В чем может заключаться проблема?

UPDATE:

```
nom_serveur = strtok_r(NULL," ", &savedptr);
while (nom_serveur)
{
    // тест находится ли мой сервер в структуре с подключенными серверами
    if (test_serveur_vide(nom_serveur, serveur_connected) == 0)          
    {   
        snprintf(requete_serveur, MAX_BUFLEN, "Le serveur de donnees %s est momentanement indiponible\n", nom_serveur);
// поиск индекса клиента в структуре с подкюченными клиентами
        index_client = recherche_login(users_connected,client.sin_port,client.sin_addr.s_addr);
        send_packet.type = ACK;
        send_packet.ack = ++users_connected -> table[index_client].ack; 
        strcpy(send_packet.packet.data, requete_serveur);
        from_struct_to_buff(send_packet,requete);
        if ((sendto(fd, requete, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client, lenclient) == -1))
            raler(1, "Erreur send");
    }

    else
    {
        index_client = recherche_login(users_connected, client.sin_port, client.sin_addr.s_addr);
        if (index_client != -1)
        {
            int droit = verifier_droit_client(users_connected -> table[index_client].login, nom_serveur, users);
            if (droit == 1)
            {
                index_serveur = recherche_port_serveur(serveur_connected, nom_serveur);
                if (index_serveur != -1)
                {
                    serveur_donnee.sin_port = serveur_connected -> table[index_serveur].port;
                    serveur_donnee.sin_addr.s_addr = serveur_connected -> table[index_serveur].address;
                    serveur_donnee.sin_family = AF_INET;

                    len = sizeof(serveur_donnee);

                    send_packet.type = ACK;
                    send_packet.ack = ++users_connected -> table[index_client].ack;
                    strcpy(send_packet.packet.data, "");
                    from_struct_to_buff(send_packet, requete);

                    if ((sendto(fd, requete, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client, lenclient) == -1))
                        raler(1, "Erreur send"); 

                    snprintf(requete_serveur, MAX_BUFLEN, "lire %s", users_connected -> table[index_client].login);

                    send_packet.type = SEQ;
                    send_packet.num_seq = serveur_connected -> table[index_serveur].num_seq;                                            
                    strcpy(send_packet.packet.data,requete_serveur);
                    from_struct_to_buff(send_packet, requete);

                    printf("Je suis LAAAA Donnees: %s\n ",requete);
                    if ((sendto(fd, requete, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serveur_donnee, len) == -1))
                        raler(1, "Erreur send"); 

                        //timeout ou pas bon ack alors sendto precedent
                    if ((recvfrom(fd, requete, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &lenclient) == -1))
                        raler(1, "Pb de recvfrom"); 

                    recv_packet = from_char_to_struct(requete);

                    if(recv_packet.type == ACK && recv_packet.ack == send_packet.num_seq + 1)
                    {
                        serveur_connected -> table[index_serveur].num_seq++;
                        printf("coooool\n");
                    }
                }
                else
                    printf("GEREEEEER");
            }
        }

        else
            printf("GEREEEEER"); 
    }
    nom_serveur = strtok_r(NULL," ", &savedptr);
}
```

Comment: Проблема в некорректном использовании `recvfrom()` (по крайней мере  вам нужно запомнить размер возвращаемый recvfrom() (скажем, в переменную `l`) и затем записать 0 в `requete[l]`) / Для более полного анализа нам нужно знать формат получаемых данных и т.п. сведения/, которые вы не описали в вопросе)

Comment: @avp попробовала, не помогло. Формат в requete: первый знак s или c, а дальше опция: write или read и название серверов,  данные которых я хочу читать. Поэтому и делаю while, потому что пользователь может ввести например read poids age taille. Данные "read poids age taille"  введены пользователем в терминале. Далее делаю snprintf и получаю такое поле, которое отправляю серверу: "c read poids age taille". c и read обрезаю в самом начале. далее while, как объясняла выше. В своем вопросе описала ситуацию когда requete="c read taille".  Поэтому while работает с "taille"

Comment: Распечатайте 1) результат `recvfrom()`, 2) `requete` после `recvfrom()`, 3) `nom_serveur` сразу после `while (nom_serveur) {` (из ответа @Fat-Zer)

Comment: @avp 1) `4096`, 2) `requete = SEQ 2 c lire taille`, 3)`strlen(requete) = 19`; 4)`nom_serveur = taille` и после этого он входит еще раз в `while (nom_serveur)` хотя должен остановиться.

Comment: Странно. Вы не забыли, что вам нужен код перебора клиентов как в ответе? Т.е. `while (nom_serveur) { ...; nom_serveur = strtok_r(0, " ", &saveptr);}` (первый аргумент второго `strtok_r()` д.б. **NULL**, а не `req`, как в первом (до `while`) вызове `strtok_r()`)

Comment: @avp Да, все верно, так и сделала

Comment: И все равно не работает? В таком случае приведите в **update** ответа свой полный тестовый не работающий код   с тестовой строкой --   `char *req[] = "taille", *sptr = 0, *s = strtok_r(req, " ", &sptr); while (s) { ... }`

Comment: @avk прикрепила, но не думаю,что проблема заключается в этом

Comment: @avp может ли проблема быть связана с использованием `strcpy`,  а не `memcpy`?

Comment: Вот здесь `nom_serveur = strtok_r(NULL," ", &savedptr);
while (nom_serveur)
{ ...` вместо NULL надо  `req`

Comment: @avp в коде выше была до этого нарезка с помощью `strtok_r`, поэтому в этот раз вызов идет с параметром NULL

Comment: Понятно. Если в конце значимых данных нуля нет, то, конечно, надо использовать `memcpy` (в любом случае, если размер известен, то memcpy лучше) / Тестовый (упрощенный до вызова **только** `strtok_r`) пример у вас работает?

Comment: Вряд ли это может иметь отношение к наблюдаемой ошибке, но все же -- параметр `addrlen` в `recvfrom()` инициализирован для вашего типа сокета правильно? Учтите -- `"The argument addrlen is a value-result argument, which the caller should initialize before the call to the size of the buffer associated with src_addr, and modified on return to indicate the actual size of the source address. The returned address is truncated if the buffer provided is too small; in this case, addrlen will return a value greater than was supplied to the call"`

Comment: Посмотрел еще раз на код. Мне не нравится, что содержимое `requete` (по сути по словам именно  в этой памяти бежит `strtok_r()`)  может меняться внутри `while`. Может стоит делать копию `requete` и делать цикл `strtok_r` именно по копии?

Comment: в обновлённом варианте первая очевидная ошибку в том, что первый вызов `strtok_r` должен делаться для корректного аргумента, а не для `NULL`...

Comment: @avp проблема была связана с использованием strcpy вместо memcpy. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Неправильно используется [`strtok_r`](http://ru.manpages.org/strtok_r/3):

- При повторных вызовах первый аргумент должен быть `NULL`.
- Третий аргумент должен быть отдельным указателем

В итоге получится что-то такое:

```
char* req = recv_packet.packet.data;
char* savedptr;

nom_serveur = strtok_r(req," ", &savedptr);
while (nom_serveur) {
  //нарезка
  nom_serveur = strtok_r(NULL," ", &savedptr);
};
```

ЗЫ: стоит не забывать, что `strtok` портит свой аргумент, так что после всех мытарств `recv_packet.packet.data` будет также испорчено.

Comment: не помогает разрешить проблему, та же проблема

Comment: @Nataila, [УМВР](https://onlinegdb.com/rkomkkZhH)